# Why is my program not working the way it should?

Tags: python

So I am supposed to write a program that takes in a list of integers and the value n and if any integers in that list are repeated more than n times, then remove all instances of that number in the list. My program right now is working for most tests but I can't figure out why it won't work for some. Here's the short code:

```
def solution(data, n): 
  if n <= 0:
      return []
  reserve=[]
  for s in data:
      if s not in reserve:
          if data.count(s) > n:
              continue
          else:
            reserve.append(s)
  del data[:]
  return reserve
```

Does anyone have any idea why it won't work? If there are any discrepancies?

Comment: Your program is working exactly as you it should; that is to say, the way you wrote it. Can you explain what it means to "not work the way it should"?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) should include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it *as formatted text* **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Specifically, what tests is it not working for?

Comment: There are some test cases that are hidden and apparently are wrong, so I'm wondering if there are any discrepancies from what I wrote and what "should" be happening, which is remove all repeated numbers.

Comment: *What are those test cases?* We can't help you if you don't tell us what's wrong.

Comment: I'm not able to know the test cases

Answer (score 0):

```
#use print statements to debug your program
data=[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4]

def solution(data, n): 
  if n <= 0:
      return []
  reserve=[]
  for s in data:
      print(reserve.count(s))
      if reserve.count(s) >= n:
         continue
      else:
         reserve.append(s)

  return reserve

res=solution(data,3)
print(res)
```

output:

```
0
1
2
3
3
0
1
2
3
0
1
2
0
1
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4]
```